# CKeditor in modal window closes when link dialog window is open

Tags: java, jquery, ckeditor

I`ve got a problem with modal window in bootstrap. The default behavior is set to close when clicking outside of a container(it has to stay that way). CKEditor is nested in that window. Everything works great but when adding a link to a text. Ckeditor opens a new dialog window in that case and while editing that link CKeditor closes. I know the reason. Bootstrap doesn't recognize that its children and therefore recognize click on link dialog window as if outside of CKEeditor.
 Is there a way to change that behavior, so link dialog window will be treated as a part of CKEditor.

this code that represents ckeditor based on bootstrap in my project. Cheers in advance!

```
(function ($) {

    var MegaEditor = function (options) {
        this.init('megaeditor', options, MegaEditor.defaults);
    };

    $.fn.editableutils.inherit(MegaEditor, $.fn.editabletypes.abstractinput);

    $.extend(MegaEditor.prototype, {
        render: function () {
            MegaEditor.superclass.render.call(this);

            //ctrl + enter
            this.$input.keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 13) {
                    $(this).closest('form').submit();
                }
            });
        },

        value2html: function(value, element) {

            $(element).html(value);
        },

        html2value: function(html) {

            return html;
        },        

        input2value: function() { 
            var wartosc = CKEDITOR.instances[this.$input.get(0).name].getData();
            return wartosc;
        },

        activate: function() {
            if(this.$input.is(':visible')) {
                $.fn.editableutils.setCursorPosition(this.$input.get(0), this.$input.val().length);
                if(CKEDITOR.instances[this.$input.get(0).name]) {
                    CKEDITOR.remove(this.$input.get(0));
                }

                CKEDITOR.replace( this.options.editorId,
                    {
                    //extraPlugins : 'uicolor',
                    language : 'pl',
                    uiColor: '#C9E3F2',
                    scayt_autoStartup: false,
                    forcePasteAsPlainText: false,
                    toolbarCanCollapse: false,
                    toolbar :
                    [
                        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Undo','Redo','-','Outdent','Indent'],
                        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                        ['Link','Unlink'], ['-','Source']

                    ]
                    } );

                this.$input.focus();
            }
        }         
    });

    MegaEditor.defaults = $.extend({}, $.fn.editabletypes.abstractinput.defaults, {
        /**
        @property tpl 
        @default <textarea></textarea>
        **/          
        tpl:'<textarea id="ckEditor"></textarea>',
        /**
        @property inputclass 
        @default input-large
        **/          
        inputclass: 'input-large',
        /**
        Placeholder attribute of input. Shown when input is empty.

        @property placeholder 
        @type string
        @default null
        **/             
        placeholder: null ,
        editorId: 'ckEditor'
    });

    $.fn.editabletypes.megaeditor = MegaEditor;    

}(window.jQuery));
```